# Autocomplete losing focus because of angular-block-ui library

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the `angular-block-ui` library to handle all my `http` requests to prevent user input.

I've implemented an autocomplete feature on my web page using an `input` and `datalist` element. My issue is, each time I enter a value into the autocomplete `block-ui` is somehow causing the `datalist` to lose focus and causing the `datalist` to flicker. After the flicker you have to click the `datalist` to see the data.

I've tried using the following code snippet to prevent the `block-ui` from appearing when entering a value into my `input` element.

```
blockUI.stop();
```

***Reference:*** https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui

However, this does not work. Has anyone come across the same issue with `block-ui` and have been able to resolve it? I'd really appreciate any feedback to help resolve my issue.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="product-code" class="col-md-2" type="text" placeholder="Product Code" name="productCode" list="search-list" ng-keyup="searchForProducts(productCode)" ng-model="productCode" />
<datalist id="search-list">
    <option ng-repeat="productCode in productCodeList" value="{{productCode}}">
</datalist>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.searchForProducts = function (productCode) {

    let code = productCode != undefined ? productCode : "";

    // when the product code is empty don't bother searching for products
    if (code != "") {

        worksOrderFactory.searchForProductCodes(productCode).then(function (data) {
            blockUI.stop();
            $scope.productCodeList = data;
        });
    }
};
```

I've also used the `blockUI.stop();` outside of the promise but still no luck.

**NB:** during testing I removed `block-ui` from my website the autocomplete works as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trial and error I was finally able to resolve my issue. I successfully prevented the `block-ui` from appear with the following line of code before my `http` call.

```
blockUIConfig.requestFilter = function () {
    return false;
};
```